# Making an array of arrays from an array of objects

Tags: arrays, angular, typescript

I have an array of objects coming back from a HTTP request in a JSON response. However, because it is coming back as an array of objects, I can index through the first array to select a specific object but I can't get any of the values out from the objects themselves.

Here is what I am getting back from my request. I would like to be able to index through the entire array as well as the objects themselves and be able to retrieve the name and values that are listed in that second level of arrays.

```
{
    "costByServiceList": [
        {
            "EC2 - Other": 0.0774193717,
            "Amazon Elastic Compute Cloud - Compute": 0.5568
        },
        {
            "EC2 - Other": 0.0774193867,
            "Amazon Elastic Compute Cloud - Compute": 0.5568,
            "AWS Cost Explorer": 0.02
        },
        {
            "EC2 - Other": 0.077419386,
            "Amazon Elastic Compute Cloud - Compute": 0.5568
        },
        {
            "EC2 - Other": 0.0774193613,
            "Amazon Elastic Compute Cloud - Compute": 0.5568
        },
        {
            "EC2 - Other": 0.0774194716,
            "Amazon Elastic Compute Cloud - Compute": 0.5568,
            "AWS Cost Explorer": 0.76
        },
        {
            "EC2 - Other": 0.0774620825,
            "Amazon Elastic Compute Cloud - Compute": 0.5568,
            "AWS Cost Explorer": 0.08
        },
        {
            "EC2 - Other": 0.0763515633,
            "Amazon Elastic Compute Cloud - Compute": 0.5568
        }
    ]
}
```

I would assume that creating an array of arrays would solve this problem but the end result doesn't require it to be an array of arrays.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys, https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/entries

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the `Object.entries` function gives you key value pairs of an object in an array of paired arrays.

```
response.costByServiceList.forEach(service => 
    Object.entries(service).forEach(([key, value]) => console.log(key, value))));
```

you could achieve what you asked like so:

```
let newServices = response.costByServiceList.map(service => Object.entries(service));
```

this would result in json like:

```
[
  [
    ["EC2 - Other", 0.0774193717],
    ["Amazon Elastic Compute Cloud - Compute", 0.5568]
  ]
]
```